# command phasescriptexecution failed with a nonzero exit code xcode 14

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, xcode14

I got the above error after I updated the Xcode to the 14.3 version. I followed this StackOverflow answer to solve that error and it worked for the first time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75921492/16529433

But when I build again I have to edit that pod file again. I am using an ionic capacitor to build the IOS app.
Is there any way to merge the pod file changes to the ionic source code?